# Converting a hexadecimal to binary

Tags: c

Im trying to figure out why this code only takes in hex numbers with 2 digits. For example, if I enter, "11" it will output, "00010001" but if I enter, "111" then it gives me some random number. I would like to try to make it accept as many digits as the user wants.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void binary_hex(int n, char hex[]);
int hex_binary(char hex[]);

int main()
{
    char hex[20],c;
    int n;

    printf("Enter hexadecimal number: ");
    scanf("%s",hex);
    printf("Binary number: %d",hex_binary(hex));

    system("pause");
    return 0;}

//Function to convert hexadecimal to binary.

int hex_binary(char hex[])   {

int i, length, decimal=0, binary=0;
for(length=0; hex[length]!='\0'; ++length);
for(i=0; hex[i]!='\0'; ++i, --length)
{
    if(hex[i]>='0' && hex[i]<='9')
        decimal+=(hex[i]-'0')*pow(16,length-1);
    if(hex[i]>='A' && hex[i]<='F')
        decimal+=(hex[i]-55)*pow(16,length-1);
    if(hex[i]>='a' && hex[i]<='f')
        decimal+=(hex[i]-87)*pow(16,length-1);
}

//At this point, variable decimal contains the hexadecimal number in decimal format. 

    i=1;
    while (decimal!=0)
    {
        binary+=(decimal%2)*i;
        decimal/=2;
        i*=10;
    }
    return binary;
}
```

Comment: Working fine for me.. It gives `100010001` output for `111` input..

Comment: What is the "some random number" that is your output?

Comment: You are storing the binary number in `int`, you should store it in `unsigned int` array.

Comment: it gives me 1999820353. It should give me 000100010001 shouldn't it?

Comment: @Learner: What if the input is `1111` or `11111`, int variable range is `−2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`?

Comment: @1336087 I changed it to unsigned int but it still gives me the wrong answer when I input more than two digits

Comment: @1336087 I know, And if input is two big say `111111111111111`it even can't stored in `unsigned int`, you need to use `string` like `data type` to store it. But I'm just saying above code is working fine on the mentioned input.

Comment: 1) use `unsigned long long decimal`  2) do not use `pow(16, )`, use `1LLU << ((length-1)*4)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an array to store the binary number, as an `int` variable won't be able to store a large number, the range of `int` is(usually) from `−32767` to `+32767`. [C data types.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)

For example:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int hex_binary(char hex[], int binary_number[]);

int main()
{
    char hex[20];
    int binary_number[100];
    int j,k;

    printf("Enter hexadecimal number: ");
    scanf("%19s",hex);
    j = hex_binary(hex,binary_number);

    printf("Binary number is: ");
    for(k=j-1;k>=0;k--)
        printf("%d",binary_number[k]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

//Function to convert hexadecimal to binary.

int hex_binary(char hex[], int binary_number[])   
{
    int i, j=0, length, decimal=0;
    for(length=0; hex[length]!='\0'; ++length);
    for(i=0; hex[i]!='\0'; ++i, --length)
    {
        if(hex[i]>='0' && hex[i]<='9')
            decimal+=(hex[i]-'0')*pow(16,length-1);
        if(hex[i]>='A' && hex[i]<='F')
            decimal+=(hex[i]-55)*pow(16,length-1);
        if(hex[i]>='a' && hex[i]<='f')
            decimal+=(hex[i]-87)*pow(16,length-1);
    }
    //At this point, variable decimal contains the hexadecimal number in decimal format. 
    while (decimal!=0)
    {
        binary_number[j++] = decimal%2;
        decimal/=2;
    }
    return j;
}
```

**Output**

```
Enter hexadecimal number: 111
Binary number is: 100010001

Enter hexadecimal number: 1111
Binary number is: 1000100010001

Enter hexadecimal number: 11111
Binary number is: 10001000100010001

Enter hexadecimal number: 987634
Binary number is: 100110000111011000110100
```

Comment: Note: The _minimum_ range of `long` is from −2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647.  The _minimum_ range of `int` is from −32,767 to 32,767.

Comment: Oh! Ok, I see what you mean. Its working now, thank you so much! I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Hi @user3047983 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.